# Grails upgrade to 3.x from 2.x. Ajax does not render template after upgrade

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, grails3

I am working on an upgrade of grails application from grails 2.5.4 to 3.1.9 and I am having trouble with ajax calls.

I have gsp templates inside my application which use ajax requests to load data from server asynchronously. Here is one of them.

Following javascript call activates ajax request.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".chosen-select").chosen();
    $(".automaticAjaxLoad").each(function () {


        var url = $(this).attr("ajaxLoadingUrl");

        if (url != "") {

            $(this).load(url);
        }
    });
});
```

This successfully calls following controller action.

```
def getLocalitiesWithCount() {
    def localitiesList = Locality.list(sort: "posOrder", order: "desc")
    def localitiesCountList = []
    localitiesList.each { locality ->
        def c = JobOffer.withCriteria() {
            createAlias("positionLocality", "_positionLocality", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
            eq("_positionLocality.id", locality.id)
            //between("l.accessDate", today, today + 1)

            gt('willExpire', new Date())
            isNotNull('datePublished')

            projections {
                // countDistinct("id")
                rowCount()
            }
        }
        def jobCountMap = [:]

        jobCountMap.put("i18NameFull", locality.i18NameFull)
        jobCountMap.put("i18Name", locality.i18Name)
        jobCountMap.put("id", locality.id)
        jobCountMap.put("name", locality.name)
        jobCountMap.put("count", c.first())

        localitiesCountList.push(jobCountMap)

        log.error('Localities count ' + localitiesCountList.size());

    }
    render(view: '/ajax/localitiesWithCount', model: [localitiesCountList: localitiesCountList])
}
```

Until this moment everything works as expected. Than it should render following gsp template, but It does not. The place where it should belong is left empty and there is no error in the console

```
<h4> ${message(code: "localities.header")} </h4>
    <hr>


        <ul style="font-size: 85%; margin: 0; list-style: none;">
            <g:each in="${localitiesCountList}"
                    status="i" var="localityInstance">

                <g:if test="${localityInstance.count != 0}" >
                <li>

                    <g:link controller="jobOffer" action="index" params="[positionLocalities: localityInstance.id]">
                        <h8>
                            ${message(code: localityInstance.i18NameFull)}

                         [${localityInstance.count}]
                        </h8>
                    </g:link>

                </li>

                </g:if>

            </g:each>

        </ul>
```

I had to rework loading of assets from resources plugin to asset-pipeline, so I guess there could be an issue, but I don't know where could be the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Since you are wanting to render a template (e.g. fragment of HTML and not a full page) you should be using `render(template: '/ajax/localitiesWithCount', model: [localitiesCountList: localitiesCountList])`and ensure that your GSP is named `_localitiesWithCount.gsp`. I suspect this will fix your issue or at least get you closer to a solution.

Comment: Thank you :). This seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are wanting to render a template (e.g. fragment of HTML and not a full page) you should be using `render(template: '/ajax/localitiesWithCount', model: [localitiesCountList: localitiesCountList])` and ensure that your GSP is named `_localitiesWithCount.gsp` since all templates must begin with an underscore.